# Loss does not decrease during training (Word2Vec, Gensim)

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, loss

What can cause loss from `model.get_latest_training_loss()` increase on each epoch?

Code, used for training:

```
class EpochSaver(CallbackAny2Vec):
    '''Callback to save model after each epoch and show training parameters '''

    def __init__(self, savedir):
        self.savedir = savedir
        self.epoch = 0

        os.makedirs(self.savedir, exist_ok=True)

    def on_epoch_end(self, model):
        savepath = os.path.join(self.savedir, "model_neg{}_epoch.gz".format(self.epoch))
        model.save(savepath)
        print(
            "Epoch saved: {}".format(self.epoch + 1),
            "Start next epoch ... ", sep="\n"
            )
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self.savedir, "model_neg{}_epoch.gz".format(self.epoch - 1))):
            print("Previous model deleted ")
            os.remove(os.path.join(self.savedir, "model_neg{}_epoch.gz".format(self.epoch - 1))) 
        self.epoch += 1
        print("Model loss:", model.get_latest_training_loss())

    def train():

        ### Initialize model ###
        print("Start training Word2Vec model")

        workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()/2

        model = Word2Vec(
            DocIter(),
            size=300, alpha=0.03, min_alpha=0.00025, iter=20,
            min_count=10, hs=0, negative=10, workers=workers,
            window=10, callbacks=[EpochSaver("./checkpoints")], 
            compute_loss=True
    )
```

Output:

Losses from epochs (1 to 20):

```
Model loss: 745896.8125
Model loss: 1403872.0
Model loss: 2022238.875
Model loss: 2552509.0
Model loss: 3065454.0
Model loss: 3549122.0
Model loss: 4096209.75
Model loss: 4615430.0
Model loss: 5103492.5
Model loss: 5570137.5
Model loss: 5955891.0
Model loss: 6395258.0
Model loss: 6845765.0
Model loss: 7260698.5
Model loss: 7712688.0
Model loss: 8144109.5
Model loss: 8542560.0
Model loss: 8903244.0
Model loss: 9280568.0
Model loss: 9676936.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Language arabian. 
As input from DocIter - list with tokens.

Comment: Please, comment you downvoting!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Up through gensim 3.6.0, the loss value reported may not be very sensible, only resetting the tally each call to `train()`, rather than each internal epoch. There are some fixes forthcoming in this issue:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/pull/2135

In the meantime, the *difference* between the previous value, and the latest, may be more meaningful. In that case, your data suggest the 1st epoch had a total loss of 745896, while the last had (9676936-9280568=) 396,368 – which may indicate the kind of progress hoped-for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But the loss is bigger on the last stage,  and as far as I understood, I only take into account the difference and should interpret it like progress, shouldn't I? And can I receive a more appropriate loss, if I'll call train() instead of just passing "iter=smth" to my model?

Comment: Calling `train()` multiple times, if you aren't already deeply familiar with the code's internal operations, often goes wrong... so I don't recommend that. (It's fragile & error-prone, & most online examples I see are wrong.) The model is generally *trying* to lower its loss after each training-example – but it may never get objectively very good at its internal word predictions, and doesn't need to for the word-vectors to still be useful for downstream tasks. (A model with lower loss doesn't necessarily give better word-vectors than one with higher!)

Comment: And it's natural for the loss-through-a-full-epoch to bounce higher and lower for a while, then eventually stop improving, upon model "convergence". That means it's as roughly as good as a model of that complexity can get, for a certain training corpus, and further epochs will just jitter the overall loss a little up and down, but no longer reliably drive it lower. So you shouldn't worry too much about the last epoch-to-epoch delta. Why is loss of interest to you?

Comment: (Separately, changing the default `alpha`/`min_alpha` isn't something I'd usually tinker with, unless sure of the reasons why and able to verify the changes are improving the results on downstream tasks.)

Comment: @DashaOrgunova, did you try to use early stopping mechanism in callback function?

Comment: @gaurav1207 no, I did not!

Comment: @gojomo, I've bumbed the gensim version, if you don't mind. (Wasn't able to edit the version number in-place)

Answer (score 5):

As proposed by **gojomo** you can calculate the difference of loss in the callback function:

```py
from gensim.models.callbacks import CallbackAny2Vec
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

# init callback class
class callback(CallbackAny2Vec):
    """
    Callback to print loss after each epoch
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.epoch = 0

    def on_epoch_end(self, model):
        loss = model.get_latest_training_loss()
        if self.epoch == 0:
            print('Loss after epoch {}: {}'.format(self.epoch, loss))
        else:
            print('Loss after epoch {}: {}'.format(self.epoch, loss- self.loss_previous_step))
        self.epoch += 1
        self.loss_previous_step = loss
```

For the training of your model and add `computer_loss = True` and `callbacks=[callback()]` in the word2vec train method:

```py
# init word2vec class
w2v_model = Word2Vec(min_count=20, 
                     window=12 
                     size=100, 
                     workers=2)
# build vovab
w2v_model.build_vocab(sentences)
  
# train the w2v model
w2v_model.train(senteces, 
                total_examples=w2v_model.corpus_count, 
                epochs=10, 
                report_delay=1,
                compute_loss = True, # set compute_loss = True
                callbacks=[callback()]) # add the callback class

# save the word2vec model
w2v_model.save('word2vec.model')
```

This will output something like this:

> Loss after epoch 0: 4448638.5
>
> Loss after epoch 1: 3283735.5
>
> Loss after epoch 2: 2826198.0
>
> Loss after epoch 3: 2680974.0
>
> Loss after epoch 4: 2601113.0
>
> Loss after epoch 5: 2271333.0
>
> Loss after epoch 6: 2052050.0
>
> Loss after epoch 7: 2011768.0
>
> Loss after epoch 8: 1927454.0
>
> Loss after epoch 9: 1887798.0